# Running shellcode on python 3?

Tags: python, shellcode

I am currently trying to port a python script from 2.7 to 3.4.2. the script should be able to run shellcode from memory.

```
from ctypes import *

shell = b"\x31\xd2\xb2\x30\x64\x8b\x12\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\..."
createbuffer= create_string_buffer(shell, len(shell))
shellcode = cast(createbuffer, CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p))

shellcode()
```

This is the closest I have gotten to running shellcode on python 3, and it just leaves me with:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0099....
```

Bear in mind that this script works 100% fine with 2.7, so i don't see why it can't be ported to 3.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, try http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The memory region in which the buffer is placed is probably protected - this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275207/python-ctypes-and-function-calls